# Hiding 3 elements in sequence not working using JavaScript "transitionend" event?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

[image: 3 boxes that explain the issue]

**WHAT**. I have 3 boxes: `blue`, `red` and `black` and I'm trying to transition them one after another, using JavaScript event listeners, in the following order: `black`, `red` and then `blue`.

**HOW**: https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/XWVeQVP?editors=1010

Basic HTML structure and nesting (pen for the complete example):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="red">
        <div id="black"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code is very simple:

```
const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
const red = document.getElementById('red');
const black = document.getElementById('black');

const hideElement = element => {
  console.log(`Hiding element ${element.getAttribute('id')}`);
  element.classList.add(element.dataset.hideClass);
};

black.addEventListener('transitionend', () => hideElement(red)); // when black transition ends, hide the red
red.addEventListener('transitionend', () => hideElement(blue)); // when red transition ends, hide the blue
hideElement(black); // hide the black (start the chain)
```

**THE PROBLEM**: after the `black` ends, `blue` and `red` start at the same time... and this is wrong because `blue` should start hiding after `red` completes. In addition, console show that the  `transitionend` event listener for `blue` is called 2 times.

Any help is much appreciated, I've be struggling with this problem since days.

[image: Console errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that because `black` is a child of `red`, the `transitionend` event got bubbled up, causing `red` to fire the event twice:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
  const red = document.getElementById('red');
  const black = document.getElementById('black');

  const hideElement = element => {
    console.log(`Hiding element ${element.getAttribute('id')}`);
    element.classList.add(element.dataset.hideClass);
  };

  black.addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();// <-- added this line
    hideElement(red);
  });
  red.addEventListener('transitionend', () => hideElement(blue));
  hideElement(black);
});
```

(Edited from your codepen; I can't fork it because I'm too lazy to register)

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty sure that was something about the propagation, but wasn't able to debug correctly. Made my day!

Answer (score 1):

transitionend event will trigger all the listeners once executed. As red and black both register the event listener before the first event triggers both a run. To prevent this, you could either pass a function which will add the event listener inside the hide element function or more preferably pass the event alongside the element and call stopPropagation. stopPropagation is an event function which will prevent the propagation of the event, thus only triggering the first one in this case

```
e?.stopPropagation()
```

Below is a modified function which should work in your context

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
  const red = document.getElementById('red');
  const black = document.getElementById('black');

  const hideElement = (element,e) => {
    console.log(`Hiding element ${element.getAttribute('id')}`);
    e?.stopPropagation()
    element.classList.add(element.dataset.hideClass);
  };
  black.addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => hideElement(red,e));
  red.addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => hideElement(blue,e));
  hideElement(black);
});
```